# How to setup the Raspberry Pi 3 onboard WiFi for Ubuntu Server 18.04 with netplan?

Tags: wifi, pi-3b+, ubuntu

How to setup of Raspberry Pi 3 B+ onboard WiFi for Ubuntu Server 18.04? In particular, with `netplan`?

This is a clean install of the [Ubuntu Server 18.04 image for Raspberry Pi 3](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/iot/raspberry-pi-2-3). File: `ubuntu-18.04.2-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi3.img.xz`.

The installed file `/etc/network/interfaces` states that `netplan` has replaced `ifupdown`.

```bsh
# ifupdown has been replaced by netplan(5) on this system.  See
# /etc/netplan for current configuration.
```

`/etc/netplan` has one file `50-cloud-init.yaml`

```
# This file is generated from information provided by
# the datasource.  Changes to it will not persist across an instance.
# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}

network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: true
            match:
                macaddress: <MAC 'eth0' [IF1]>
            set-name: eth0
```

Netplan.io provides some general [Netplan configuration examples](https://netplan.io/examples).

> To configure netplan, save configuration files under `/etc/netplan/` with a `.yaml` extension (e.g. `/etc/netplan/config.yaml`), then run `sudo netplan apply`.

... yet, no guideance specific to a RaspberryPi. ...in particular, with respect to the *existing /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml* file on the RaspberryPi Ubuntu Server install.

What would be the `netplan` template for the RaspberryPi? Can the existing `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d` be left enabled? What is lost if `cloud.cfg.d` on the Raspberry Pi is disabled? ... (... and, wondering ... how much of this issue needs RaspPi knowledge vs. Ubuntu knowledge.)

*Note: Since this question is at the intersection of Ubuntu & Raspberry Pi, a related question was also posted on [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1143287).*

Comment: I'm not in a position to test right now (as my only connection to my Pis is over SSH right now, so if it doesn't work i'll lose connection), but [this page](https://gist.github.com/Jiab77/76000284f8200da5019a232854421564) here might fill in some of the blanks you need for the netplan and setting your country for the Wifi. I'll give this a test tonight if you're not having any luck.

Comment: @Larnu The "[Raspberry Pi 3B/B+ Wireless Bridge using Ubuntu Server 18.04 ARM Image and Netplan](https://gist.github.com/Jiab77/76000284f8200da5019a232854421564)"  link you provide included the needed steps. The essential steps needed for this particular question are now summarized as an answer. So, success. :-) Thanks.

Comment: Glad to see you got there. Would have had a go today of no but I see there's no need. :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The steps below were found to provide a persistent WiFi setup using `netplan` with Ubuntu Server 18.04 `ubuntu-18.04.2-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi3.img.xz` image on a Raspberry Pi 3 B+.

Update system:

```bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
sudo reboot
```

Determine interface names:

```bash
ip link show

# 1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> …
# 2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> … state UP …
# 3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> … state DOWN
```

Determine your-cloud-init.yaml and open for editing.

```bash
cd /etc/netplan/
ls -l
# -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 666 May 15 22:00 50-cloud-init.yaml
### note your *cloud-init.yaml file name

### backup *cloud-init.yaml file
cp 50-cloud-init.yaml 50-cloud-init.yaml.bak
### restrict read access
sudo chmod 640 /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml
### edit *cloud-init.yaml
sudo nano 50-cloud-init.yaml
```

Add WiFi access information to your-cloud-init.yaml file.

```yaml
# This file is generated from information provided by
# the datasource.  Changes to it will not persist across an instance.
# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            optional: true
            dhcp4: true
    # add wifi setup information here ...
    wifis:
        wlan0:
            optional: true
            access-points:
                "YOUR-SSID-NAME":
                    password: "YOUR-NETWORK-PASSWORD"
            dhcp4: true
```

Test, generate and apply the changed your-cloud-init.yaml config:

- Testing: `sudo netplan --debug try` (continue even if there are errors)
- Generate: `sudo netplan --debug generate` (provides more details in case of issues with the previous command)
- Apply: `sudo netplan --debug apply` (if no issues during the previous commands)

Confirmation Test:

```bash
sudo reboot

### wait, then without the wired ethernet connected ... 
ssh ubuntu@wifi-ip-address
```

*The above sequence was distilled from the "[Raspberry Pi 3B/B+ Wireless Bridge using Ubuntu Server 18.04 ARM Image and Netplan](https://gist.github.com/Jiab77/76000284f8200da5019a232854421564)" gist link mentioned in the question comments by [Larnu](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/103117/larnu).  The gist goes well beyond just enabling WiFi since its turns the Pi into a Bridge.*

---

Some additional useful WiFi setup steps.

*Set hostname.*

```
sudo hostnamectl set-hostname my-server-name
```

`sudo nano /etc/hosts`

```bash
127.0.0.1 localhost
# add host name
127.0.0.1 my-server-name
```

`sudo nano /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg`

```ini
# Set preserve_hostname to true for persistance after reboot
preserve_hostname: true
```

Verify from local Raspberry Pi commandline.

```bash
hostnamectl
#   Static hostname: my-server-name
#         Icon name: computer
#        Machine ID: …
#           Boot ID: …
#  Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
#            Kernel: Linux 4.15.0-1036-raspi2
#      Architecture: arm64
```

*Enable mDNS.*

If desired, enable [Multicast DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS) by installing [Avahi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avahi_(software)). Avahi supports the mDNS/DNS-SD/RFC 3927/Zeroconf/Bonjour specification.

```bash
sudo apt install avahi-daemon
```

Remotely check mDNS resolution from another computer.

```bash
ping my-server-name.local
ssh ubuntu@my-server-name.local
```

Comment: This is awesome! All steps described work with the pi 4

Comment: Also works with Ubuntu 19.10.1 (I used this with ubuntu-19.10.1-preinstalled-server-armhf+raspi3.img.xz on a Pi 3).

Comment: This worked on the `ubuntu-20.04-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi.img.xz` image, thanks!

Comment: These steps worked at first but now I don't see the wifi connected anymore. I haven't touched the config at all. I am on RaspberryPi 4 with Ubuntu Server 20.4 `Linux ubuntu 5.4.0-1015-raspi #15-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 10 05:34:24 UTC 2020 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux`. Any faced this issue? I have tried following the steps again and it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: ```sudo chmod 640 /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml``` ;-)

Comment: Worked like a charm on 'ubuntu-18.04.4-preinstalled-server-armhf+raspi3.img.xz' Thanks!

Comment: This works exactly as expected. Thank GOD someone had the correctly formatted YAML. You have no idea how many answers didn't have it right.

Comment: @ScotchAndSoda You saved my day! Why do I have to change permission to 640?

Comment: @draw, it is always better to restrict files with sensitive data to root only. If you leave it with 644, every connected user may be able to know your wifi password ;-)

Comment: Working for model 4b o/